# SAS Filename statement to refer an aggregate storage location

Tags: sas, filenames

I am a beginner of SAS.

I am trying to refer an external aggregate storage location by using FILENAME statement. The statement I wrote down is the following:

```
FILENAME SAMPLE 'c:\users\My SAS Files\9.3';
```

After executing it, I got the error message in log.

```
9221  FILENAME SAMPLE 'C:\Users\My SAS Files\9.3';
      --------
      23
ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name FILENAME.

9221! FILENAME SAMPLE 'C:\Users\My SAS Files\9.3';
               ------
               23
ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name SAMPLE.
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to fix it? I read through the documentation of FILENAME statement, seems it can be used to refer a folder.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behaviour in a new SAS session, if you just run this one statement and nothing else?

Comment: That isn't an error from `FILENAME`, it's an error suggesting something is wrong before it (so SAS thinks you're in a different context).

Comment: Yeah, I am running only this one statement and nothing else. I cannot do that in SAS? Thank you.  reply to user667489

Comment: Okay. Hmm,,,, something wrong before it. Should I add a LIBNAME before it? reply to Joe

Comment: I added a statement in front of FILENAME statement. LIBNAME SAMPLE1 'c:\users\My SAS files\9.3'; then both of them work now. interesting.

Comment: Then you have something else weird going on.

Comment: Hi Joe, I closed the program and quit SAS. Then I open SAS again and open the program. run it again. this time no problem.

Comment: Hello Joe and user667489, I think I got what you mean. I actually did run a FILENAME statement before this one, that one refer a specific file in the same folder. Then I wanted to see if I can refer a folder. So maybe that is what you two were talking about: a different session or different context. Did I understand it correctly now? I made SAS confused :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of what can happen when you leave out a semi-colon.

The error is NOT saying there is anything wrong with your FILENAME statement.  Instead it is saying the adding the keyword FILENAME to the statement that it is currently interpreting is not valid. That statement (not shown in your question) does not allow the keywords FILENAME or SAMPLE.